# VSCode linkify tickets / custom rules?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way in VSCode (or using an existing extension) to define a rule that turns e.g. `#123` into a clickable link to a ticket tracker?

This was [asked on VSCode's Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61223) in 2018:

> This is doable from an extension. We have link provider API so any extension can mark any region of code as a link and open a custom URL when the link is clicked.

Does such an extension exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Autolink](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.autolink) extension can link any ticket tracker URL by regular expression rules.

Answer (score 1):

There's this [Link Github Issues](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dt.ghlink) extension I've been using for a while that seems to work well:

[image]

[image]